# Why does Oli have his own search engine while the rest of us poor folk have to use the site's search box?

Tags: discussion, fun

Anyone want to explain [this](http://askoli.quickmediasolutions.com/)?

[image: NOOOOOOOO! We will NEVER be this famous!]

Comment: You can probably explain it the best. Given it's hosted at your server :P

Comment: And he paid you how much to do this? ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because he is carelessly nice and apparently has good enough friends with enough free time that like to create search engines with his name in it! ;)

Comment: Lol... it took me all of 20 minutes :P